# Is it possible to validate types at runtime in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to validate that an object has attributes defined by an interface at runtime?
I'm trying to make an API call from client side and I would to validate that the result is of the type that I'm expecting it to be. Here is an example:

```
interface IEvent {
  id: string;
  title: string;
}

function get(id: string) {
  const client = new Api({});
  client.get<IEvent>(`/api/events/${id}.json`).then((response: AxiosResponse<IEvent>) => {
    const { data } = response;
    // validate that `data` has attributes in IEvent interface
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript types are erased at compile time. In fact, the most popular (actually, as far as I know, the *only*) implementation of TypeScript simply compiles to ECMAScript, which doesn't have types.

It would *theoretically* be possible to compile the types in such a way that they are retained in ECMAScript, but the TypeScript team has specified that types *must* be erased at compile time. The reason for this is that [they want to make it possible for Babel to compile TypeScript](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/typescript-and-babel-7/) as well, and Babel doesn't known anything about TypeScript types; it literally just deletes the type information.