# Can you echo a type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

As far as I'm aware there is nothing in TypeScript like:

```
type TypeA = { x: number };
printType(TypeA);
```

Here is the only approach I've found to consistently get TypeScript to output a description of a type.

```
const y = {
    x: 1,
    z: 'hello',
};

const z: never = y;
```

Attempting to assign to a `never` type will always print an error and the error mentions the type of the value being assigned.

```
Type '{ x: number; z: string; }' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

This approach is limited because it requires a real variable.

Is there really no other way?

Comment: Hover over the variable?

Comment: Are you not using an IntelliSense-enabled IDE?  If you can [get it to tell you the types](https://tsplay.dev/Wk8qLw).  If not then, uh, why not?  What IDE are you using?

Comment: @zenly Introspection can be very useful, eg for debugging.

Comment: @jcalz, zenly: Ideally tsc would do this and it wouldn't matter how the developer wrote the code

Comment: Could you describe a use case non-IDE use case where you want that info? Every time I've ever wanted TS to tell me what types things are, I'm using an IDE. I could *imagine* someone using a plain text editor, wondering what a type is, so they compile it with tsc, then scan through the output looking for the relevant logging info... but I could *also* imagine someone writing TS using Morse code over a telegraph machine and then receiving type information via smoke signals or semaphore, and I don't see why anyone would expect tooling provided for such development modes. What am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz your comment was funny :)) I can mention one scenario where we faced a similar issue: statically analyzing typescript code. In our context we did tricks similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75865839/extract-inferred-return-type-with-typescript-api) to get type info ... maybe the OP means something like that

Comment: @OrenIshShalom Why not use the compiler API then? You'll get type info as AST nodes, not strings.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to do this at runtime, because [TypeScript types are necessarily erased at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63533129/is-it-possible-to-validate-types-at-runtime-in-typescript). Consequently, you'll only be able to do this in your IDE or as part of the compilation process, before TypeScript becomes runnable JavaScript. Your workaround of emitting this as a compilation error is effective because it happens during compile; there's no way using official TS to make it work at runtime.

That said, the availability of [tsserver](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Standalone-Server-(tsserver)) has made it easy for many IDEs to integrate type information. That page also includes some sample integrations, though many others are available. Foremost in those is Microsoft's own Visual Studio Code, which offers both [IntelliSense](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-editing#_intellisense) (popups, hover-over, and code completion) and  [inlay hints](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-editing#_inlay-hints) (parameter and type information rendered inline as if written explicitly).

Finally, a documentation-oriented language extension called [Twoslash](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#handbook-11) makes explicit requests to the IDE to display the type inline. This works much like the inlay hints above but is opt-in for points you specify. It is available automatically in TypeScript Playground and [extensions are available to add Twoslash support to VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Orta.vscode-twoslash-queries).

```
const a = { b: 3, c: "hello" };

console.log(a);
//          ^? [const a: { b: number, c: string }]
```

As in the [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA3jARgLhgZgDQzDYBEAFgKYA2lIxMAvgNwBQzokIl5AdDQOYAKOAEoWAejEwp0mQD0A-MyA), the type annotation in the square brackets is added and updated automatically.

Comment: Do you know if anyone has ever proposed adding a compile-time feature like this to TypeScript?

Comment: ^ If someone proposes this I imagine it would be declined with a note saying to use tsserver or the compiler API or twoslash, etc.,

Comment: @dankuck In which channel would you expect this information? In broad strokes the compiler takes in source and outputs compiled code, possibly with warning messages or errors. If you want this data in a structured IDE-like way, tsserver is built for that purpose. if you want it persistent and human readable from a compiler, then it would get unmanageable super quick. If you want it ephemeral and human readable, you could do what you do above with assignment or wrap it into a function with a single parameter of type `never`. Really, though, this kind of tooling is exactly what IDEs are for.

Comment: @jeff-bowman All the TypeScript output I see is on the command line as error messages. That's where I'd expect a feature like this to output as well. I'm sure some people find those error messages unmanageable, but some people prefer them. It's really a matter for developer preference, like anything in an IDE.

You've helped me see why this question is hard to Google for. Most people have no reason to ask this question because they get by with and prefer what their IDE already provides. 

But Twoslash's `^?` seems like an inline version of this feature, so I guess it has come up before.